# Retrieving data from multiple tables and represent it in combo box in Laravel

Tags: php, database, laravel

I have Course table in my database which connect one to many with Location table , 
when I try to add new course to the table , I choose the Location of that course which presented as (Class a , Class b , ...) , but when I try to edit that course location the presented data is the id of that location not it name

I write this code in CourseController for editing :

```
 public function edit(Course $course)
{
    $locations = Location::all();
    $loc =array();
    foreach($locations as $location)
    $loc[$location->id]=$location->name_location;

 return view('admin.courses.edit',compact('course','loc','locations'));
}
```

and update function

```
    public function update(Request $request, Course $course)
{

    $course->update($request->all());
    $course->location_id = $request->input('location_id');
    return redirect()->route('courses.index')
                    ->with('success','location updated successfully');
}
```

In edit.blade I try this

```
      <select name='location_id' style="width:220px;">

                        <option value="{{$locations}}">{{$course->location_id}}</option>

                      </select>
```

in Course model

```
 public function location(){

    return $this->belongsTo('App\Location');
   }
```

in Location model

```
 public function courses(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Course');
}
```

I want want to be able to edit the location of a course
Knowing insert correct but edite No

Could someone tell me what to do to fix this ?
I use Laravel 5.7

Comment: To clarify, do you want to be able to edit the location of a course? Can you please post your relationship between course and location?

Comment: For more clarification do you want the name of the course in the url instead of the id?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have :

Location with properties : id, name

Location hasMany Course

Course belongsTo Location

```
public function edit(Course $course)
{
    $locations = Location::all();

    return view('admin.courses.edit',compact('course','locations'));
}
```

In your blade :

```
<select name='location_id' style="width:220px;">
    @foreach ($locations as $location)
      <option value="{{$location->id}}">{{$location->name}}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

Comment: - consider using autocomplete if you have too many locations

- consider using custom requests to validate your datas (https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation#creating-form-requests)

Comment: When using the code set by the selection it existed but there were no options that were null and had no value with it

Comment: you can add before @foreach : <option value="null">None</option>